# Unable to list my Github repositories when creating Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create an Azure Pipeline (using the classical interface) that should checkout a private Github.com Enterprise repository (in an organization under https://github.com/enterprise), but Azure does not find any repository:
[image]

I have tried with both Oauth authentication and with a PAT with `repos` scope. Even with the *Load all repositories* button, Azure always says *No repositories found*.

Trying to type the / directly in the field does not work either, as the field is still marked in red with *This setting is required*.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you access private github repo on any VPN?

Comment: @SanjayChoudhary Both Azure DevOps and Github.com are on the public internet, no VPN involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a service connection with your GitHub Enterprise. This is a bit hidden and I didn't manage to create it directly.

To workaround it, in the pipeline creation process, choose the YAML version(not the classic, just to create the connection).

[image]

On the next screen scroll all the way to the bottom and click in **You may also select a specific connection.** There you will be able to authorize and create the service connection and choose it on your classic pipeline.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! For future readers, you have to actually go and save the yaml pipeline in order for the connection to be created and available in the Classic Pipeline page.